# How to convert generated x509certificate to Hex in Java

Tags: java, hex, x509certificate

I generate a x509certificate with Java, but I need to convert this x509certificate to Hex.

```
X509Certificate generateX509Certificate() throws Exception
```

{

```
X509CertificateStructure x509CertificateStructure = generateX509CertificateHolder().toASN1Structure();

CertificateFactory certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");

InputStream is1 = new ByteArrayInputStream(x509CertificateStructure.getEncoded());
X509Certificate x509Certificate = (X509Certificate)certificateFactory.generateCertificate(is1);
return x509Certificate;
```

other alternative is the byte[] but I don't know how to convert it to hex.
Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution

```
byte[] hex = x509Certificate.getEncoded();

  System.out.println("--------------------------------------");

  String hexText = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(hex);
  System.out.println(hexText);
```